# How to achieve this hover effect?

Tags: css, hover, mousehover

I'm trying to figure out how the hover effect on links (in the WORK section) is achieved on this website: http://weaintplastic.com/

Can it be done with CSS animations? Or is there JavaScript involved?

I tried using CSS transition, but I can't get both elements to move at the same time.

Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried?  Can you post your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done with CSS :hover selector.

What they are doing here is they are giving the **bottom** text

```
opacity: 0;
transform: translateY(-10px);
transition: .25s cubic-bezier(.165,.84,.44,1);
```

and they are giving the **upper** text

```
transform: translateY(10px);
transition: .25s cubic-bezier(.165,.84,.44,1);
```

What that does is smoothly rearranges the text, as well as hides the bottom one.

**Edit:**

The CSS is linked like this:

```
.project-link:hover .link__headline
.project-link:hover .link__subline
```

In this way, when .project-link gets hovered, bottom and upper text get animated at the same time.

Comment: Yes! The linking part was what I couldn't figure out. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 1):

It can be done with CSS:

```
.project-nav .project-link:hover .link__headline {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(10px);
    -ms-transform: translateY(10px);
    transform: translateY(10px);
}

.project-nav .project-link:hover .link__subline {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-10px);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-10px);
    transform: translateY(-10px);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I got it!

Answer (score 0):

It can be done with only using CSS animation.
I made an example:

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}

a.animation-link {
  letter-spacing: .1em;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.animation-link .link__headline,
.animation-link .link__subline {
  -webkit-transition: .25s cubic-bezier(.165, .84, .44, 1);
  -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
}

.animation-link .link__headline {
  display: block;
  font-size: 1.25em;
}

.animation-link:hover .link__headline {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(10px);
  -ms-transform: translateY(10px);
  transform: translateY(10px);
}

.animation-link .link__subline {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: transparent;
  transition: .25s cubic-bezier(.165, .84, .44, 1);
  -ms-transform: translateY(0);
  transform: translateY(0);
  min-width: 0;
  opacity: 1;
  color: green;
}

.animation-link:hover .link__subline {
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-10px);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-10px);
  transform: translateY(-10px);
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <a class="animation-link" href="#">
    <span class="link__headline">Pulp Fiction Movie</span>
    <h6 class="link__subline">by Quentin Tarantino</h6>
  </a>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks! I couldn't figure out how to properly combine the selectors. This is perfect.