# How To Give Effect Particle while mouse move and Luminous while hover in canvas

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation, canvas

I hope this Question is still accepted in Stack Overflow since **What I want to Know is The technique to make this effect**. Recently I found a very cool website Landing animation that give effect such as light particle (this looks like parallax.js as far as I know) that moving while we move our mouse and a Luminous effect while hovering in a specific location.

I know fully that we can Achieve Hover using css and light particle using javascript, but how can I achieve this while using a canvas like in this website for example? when I tried to inspect element of this site, it seems using canvas to achieve this, so I'm curious if I want to make a website like this, what is the technique I must learn since I'm quite confused where to start if I want to achieve this kind of effect?

reference site: [Genshin Impact landing page](https://genshin.mihoyo.com/en)

the effect that I want to achieve:

[image: While we not hovering to this element]

[image: While we Hovering to this element, reproduce a luminous effect]

[image: When inspecting element it only give canvas as HTML Renderer]

Can someone help me or tell me where must I start if I want to achieve this, since I want to try learning to make this kind of cool Effect using css and Js?

some article that I read:

1. [2-ways-to-create-an-animated-particle-background](https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/2-ways-to-create-an-animated-particle-background--cms-30224)
2. [particles-animation-codepen](https://www.jotform.com/blog/particles-animation-codepen-97659/)
3. [particle-animation-code-snippets](https://speckyboy.com/particle-animation-code-snippets/)
4. [easing-animations-in-canvas/](https://css-tricks.com/easing-animations-in-canvas/)
5. [how-to-achieve-this-hover-effect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60367753/how-to-achieve-this-hover-effect)

Answer (score 0):

Websites like these are built using WebGL which uses GPU to render these 3d effects. GPU usage is only possible through the canvas as of now.
There are various javascript libraries out there through which you can achieve such results. The most popular among them is **three.js**. It is used to build amazing 3d websites nowadays. Some other libraries are babylon.js, particle.js etc.